# Guardar datos desde el controlador de una tabla que tiene asociada una tabla secundaria con clave foranea Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, blade

no sé si me he explicado bien en el título ya que no sabía como expresarlo en tan pocas palabras pero pongo en contexto.

Tengo una tabla que carga productos y otra tabla asociada a esta mediante el product_id que carga las imagenes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde el controlador del Producto tengo un método para registrar productos y guardarlos en la base de datos.

El conflicto lo tengo al guardar las imagenes, ya que no sabría como acceder a la tabla Product_images desde el controlador. Desde las vistas sé que es con un foreach recorriendola tal que así:

```
@foreach($product->product_images as $product_image)
<p>{{$product_image->image}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Pero desde las vistas no sé como hacerlo.

Aquí les dejo el método para subir la imagen que he hecho en el controlador, a ver si me pueden ayudar.

```
$category_id = $request->get('categoria_id');
        $name = $request->input('name');
        $brand = $request->input('brand');
        $price = $request->input('price');

        $files = $request->file('image');

        /*$validate = $this->validate($request, [
            'category_id' => ['required'],
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],
            'brand' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],
            'price' => ['required', 'between:0,9999.99'],
            'image' => ['required', 'image']
        ]);*/


        $product = new Product();
        $product->category_id = $category_id;
        $product->name = $name;
        $product->brand = $brand;
        $product->price = $price;

        $product->save();

        //Instancia de ProductImage
        $product_image = new ProductImage();
        if ($files) {

            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $file_name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

                //Ya que vamos a guardar las imagenes en la tabla Product_images y no en la de Product
                //Tenemos que recoger el ID de product y hacer otro insert dentro de esa tabla
                $product_image->product_id = $product->id;

                //Guardar img
                $product_image->image = $file_name;

                //Hacemos el save
                $product_image->save();

                \Storage::disk('products')->put($file_name, \File::get($file));
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('product.all')->with(['message' => 'Imagenes no subidas']);
        }

        return redirect()->route('product.all')->with(['message' => 'Producto creado!!']);
```

También el HTML de la imagen:

```
<input id="image" multiple="multiple" type="file" class="form-control" name="image[]"/>
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar y gracias!

**código del controlador editado!!**

Answer (score 0):

La solucion es simple, se realiza con los siguientes pasos

1. Obtenemos el `id` del producto guardado con `$product->id`
2. Guardamos las imagenes con ese `id`

```
$category_id = $request->get('categoria_id');
$name = $request->input('name');
$brand = $request->input('brand');
$price = $request->input('price');

$files = $request->file('image');

$product = new Product();
$product->category_id = $category_id;
$product->name = $name;
$product->brand = $brand;
$product->price = $price;

//Guardamos el producto
$product->save();

//Instanciamos el modelo ProductImage
$produc_image = new ProductImage();

if ($files && is_array($files) || $files && is_object($files)) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $file_name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        
        //Guardamos el id del producto insertado
        $produc_image->product_id = $product->id;
        //Guardamos la imagen
        $produc_image->image = $file_name;
        //Finalmente guardamos el producto con la imagen
        $produc_image->save();

        \Storage::disk('products')->put($file_name, \File::get($file));
    }
} else {
    return redirect()->route('product.all')->with(['message' => 'Imagenes no subidas']);
}

return redirect()->route('product.all')->with(['message' => 'Producto creado!!']);
```

En este caso estoy asumiendo que tu `Modelo` se llama `ProductImage`

Debes fijarte en las relaciones que tienes, si la relacion de "Product-Product_images" seria de "uno-uno" (Aunque si es asi es mejor incluir las imagenes dentro de la tabla Product) se podria hacer lo que hicistes, pero en este caso es de `uno-muchos` por lo cual tienes que tomar la tabla "Product_images" para poder insertar las imagenes de tus productos

Comment: Hola! ya lo tengo funcionando. Tan solo me falta algo y es que unicamente guarda un elemento recorrido del foreach en lugar de todos